# NodeJS - udefined variable in a recursive function call

Tags: node.js, for-loop, recursion

I have this code that I implemented for a breadth search in a graph,
I putted the variable in an array and I need to call the recursive function 
Here is the code sample to fully understand

```
var completed =[];
 var visited = [] ;
 var id = 0

function breadth (id) {
    completed.push(id);
    if (graph[id][1].length > 0){
      for (i in graph[id][1]){
          node = graph[id][1][i];
          id = node.id ;
          visited.push (i) ;
          breadth(id);  
      }

    }
}
breadth (id) ;
```

it keep showing this error msg :

> if (graph[id][1].length > 0){
>                    ^
>   TypeError: Cannot read property '1' of undefined

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Well for whatever reason `graph[id]` is undefined in one of the calls (that's what the error message is saying). You might be able to fix the problem from there.

Comment: Where did you define variable 'graph' ?

Comment: i think the problem where there is no elements in the graph[1]..its undefined so you cannot do .length property on it thatz why it shows the error juzt print the graph evry time gets in to the loop..check whether the values are not 'undefined'.if it is undefined you cant do 
.length on it it will show error